# add layout to splashscreen

Tags: xamarin.android, splash-screen, mvvmcross

Is it possible to add a layout to the MvxSplashScreenActivity? I have overiden the OnViewModelSet like in all the other activities and placed the following code:

```
protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        base.OnViewModelSet ();
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
    }
```

The layout I am trying to load is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/applogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" /></RelativeLayout>
```

and I am getting the following exception:

> Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to resolve type
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContextStack`1[[Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.IMvxAndroidBindingContext,
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]

I cant seem to find anything online regarding the mvvmcross splash screen..

Ahy Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a databound layout within the splashscreen - the splashscreen is displayed before mvvmcross is fully started.

However, for a simple layout, you do pass a resource Id down to the base class constructor:

```
public class SplashScreen : MvxSplashScreenActivity
{
    public SplashScreen()
        : base(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen)
    {
    }
}
```

Further - to avoid black start screens - most people use a theme to specify a whole screen image in their splashscreen - see the 'standard' splash screen supplied by nuget - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/nuspec/DroidContent/SplashScreen.cs.pp

Comment: It's not ideal approach for Android to embed Splash image because of different proportions of screens, thus distorted bitmap images. SplashScreen.axml should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure Initialize Setup before calling OnCreate.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            var setupSingleton = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this);
            setupSingleton.EnsureInitialized();

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
        }
```